# calling ffmpeg from python in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am currently writing my first python script to split large audio files into smaller ones. (Splitting Albums into individual tracks):

```
import subprocess

def genList():
    with open("commands.txt") as file:
        ffmpeg_template_str = 'ffmpeg -i audio.FLAC -acodec copy -ss START_TIME -to END_TIME LITTLE_FILE'
        lines = file.readlines()
        results = []

        for line in lines:
            argument_list = line.split(' ')
            result = ffmpeg_template_str
            results.append(result.replace('START_TIME', argument_list[0]).replace('END_TIME', argument_list[1]).replace('LITTLE_FILE', argument_list[2]))
    return results;

def split():
    commands = genList()
    for command in commands:
        subprocess.call(command.split(' '))

split()
```

When i execute the script, many command line windows will pop up, but only the last delivers the desired result.

So if i want to split an audio file into smaller files only the last split operation seems to executed correctly.

Additionally if i dont use a for loop and just paste subprocess.call multiple times into the code it works just fine.

```
subprocess.call(command1)
subprocess.call(command2)
subprocess.call(command3)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `argument_list = line.split(' ');` => `argument_list = line.split()` or last argument has the linefeed character. not good

Comment: then fix your indentation and remove the semicolons, python doesn't need them

Comment: you should check the return value you get from `subprocess.call()` and make sure it is 0 if you want to make sure it works as intended.

Comment: or use `check_call`